# Typescript the lines of code inside base component is not getting executed and not able to set debug point

Tags: typescript, angular7

I am working on my angular 7.x application. The application is using my library code. everything working fine locally and when i deploy to another environment its not working as expected. When debug, able to see that the lines of code inside base component constructor is not being executed for some reason. Its really driving my crazy. Can anyone help me what could be the reason?

Here is my component and the base component, which is available in a library:

```
export class AdminReportsComponent extends ContextSensitiveBaseComponent {

    constructor(private adminReportService: AdminReportService,
        helpService: ContextSensitiveHelpService,
        pageConfigurationService: PageConfigurationService
        ){
        super(helpService, pageConfigurationService, '/Declaration/ConflictOfInterest/Index');
    }
}

export class ContextSensitiveBaseComponent implements AfterViewInit, OnDestroy {

    constructor(
        protected helpService: ContextSensitiveHelpService,
        protected pageConfigurationService: PageConfigurationService,
        @Optional() @Inject(PAGEHELP_TOKEN) protected pageGuid = ''
    ) {
    //Following lines of code are not getting exeucted and not able to set the debug points
      this.pageConfigurationService.configure(new PageConfigurationOption({
        helpGuid: this.pageGuid,
        showPageHelp: true,
      }));
    } 
}
```

Comment: What happens when you set a break point on the `super` call and step into that?

Comment: It goes to the base constructor and not inside the constructor